# Unknown property error for exit in Groovysh

Tags: groovy

When I am giving exit command in Groovysh command prompt I am getting following error. Other commands are working fine.

```
Groovy Shell (2.3.6, JVM: 1.8.0_25)
...
groovy:000> exit
Unknown property: exit
groovy:000>
```

I tried with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and it is also working fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`exit` was replaced with `:exit`, but unfortunately I don't remember in which version it was introduced.

**EDIT**
I've found it. See [this](https://twitter.com/kenkousen/status/463656597068058624) tweet.

Comment: You can also use shorter variants of these commands, for example `:x` for `:exit`. Type `:help` to get full list.

Answer (score 2):

As per this page, http://groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html (See 1.4.1. Recognized Commands), the **ONLY** way to exit the shell is by pressing :x or :exit.

You can also do so by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, however it will give a warning of an abnormal termination of JVM.